# C# asynchronous threading API crawler

Tags: c#, api, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I have a program that sends/receives POST requests/responses from an online API, similar to a market bot that buys and sells a commodity. It works great, however when i run it, it locks up the current thread and im unable to use anything else in the program. In the future i would also like to make buying and selling asynchronous, so they could happen at the same time. Here is the code that executes, and as you can see it loops continuously until conditions are met:

```
private void RunBot()
{
    numToBuy = (int)nudNumToBuy.Value;

    for (int i = 0; i < numToBuy; i++)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (AttachAndBuy())
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
private bool AttachAndBuy()
{
    string data = "<DATA HERE>";
    string URL = "<URL HERE>";

    Cookies.SetCookies(cookie, "PHPSESSID=" + SessionIDTextBox.Text.Replace("PHPSESSID=", ""));
    HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
    Request.ContentType = "application/json";
    Request.Accept = "*/*";
    Request.CookieContainer = Cookies;
    Request.Host = "<HOST HERE>";
    Request.Method = "POST";
    Request.UserAgent = "<USER AGENT HERE>";
    Request.Headers.Add("<HEADER>", "<VALUE>");
    Request.KeepAlive = true;

    byte[] CompressedRequest = SimpleZlib.CompressToBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), 9);
    Stream RequestStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
    RequestStream.Write(CompressedRequest, 0, CompressedRequest.Length);
    RequestStream.Flush();

    Stream CompressedResponseStream = Request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
    byte[] CompressedResponseData = ReadToEnd(CompressedResponseStream);
    string DecompressedResponseData = SimpleZlib.Decompress(CompressedResponseData, null);

    OffersResponse Return = Json.Deserialize<OffersResponse>(DecompressedResponseData);

    int LowestCost = 1000000000;
    Offer BestOffer = new Offer();

    foreach (Offer CurrentOffer in Return.data.offers)
    {
        bool moneyOffer = false;
        int Costs = CurrentOffer.requirementsCost;
        string id = CurrentOffer._id;

        foreach (Requirement CurrentRequirement in CurrentOffer.requirements)
        {
            if (CurrentRequirement._tpl == "<TEMPLATE ID HERE>")
            {
                moneyOffer = true;
            }
        }

        if (moneyOffer == false)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (Costs < LowestCost)
        {
            LowestCost = Costs;
            BestOffer = CurrentOffer;
        }
    }

    BestOfferID = BestOffer._id;
    BestOfferCost = LowestCost;

    string MoneyID = getStack(BestOfferCost);
    while (true)
    {
        BuyRequestAttemptCounter++;

        if (LowestCost > 140000)
        {
            AddLog("No Suitable Item! Skipping! Lowest Item Cost: " + LowestCost.ToString());
            return false;
        }
        else
            AddLog("Best Item Cost: " + LowestCost.ToString() + " | ID: " + BestOfferID);

        int Result = buyOrder(MoneyID);
        if (Result == 0)
        {
            //log info for averaging
            numberPurchased++;
            TotalCost += BestOfferCost;
            averageCost = TotalCost / numberPurchased;

            lblNumPurchased.Text = numberPurchased.ToString();
            lblAverageCost.Text = averageCost.ToString();
            lstPricesPurchased.Items.Add(LowestCost.ToString());

            AddLog("====================================");
            AddLog("Number Purchased: " + numberPurchased);
            AddLog("Average Cost: " + averageCost);
            AddLog("====================================");
            System.Media.SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();
            return true;
        }
        else if (Result == 1)
            return false;
        else if (Result == 2)
            continue;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

```
private int buyOrder(string MoneyID)
{
    string data = "<DATA HERE>";
    string URL = "<URL HERE>";

    Cookies.SetCookies(cookie, "PHPSESSID=" + SessionIDTextBox.Text.Replace("PHPSESSID=", ""));
    HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
    Request.ContentType = "application/json";
    Request.Accept = "*/*";
    Request.CookieContainer = Cookies;
    Request.Host = "<HOST HERE>";
    Request.Method = "POST";
    Request.UserAgent = "<USER AGENT HERE>";
    Request.Headers.Add("<HEADER>", "<VALUE>");
    Request.KeepAlive = true;

    byte[] CompressedRequest = SimpleZlib.CompressToBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), 9);
    Stream RequestStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
    RequestStream.Write(CompressedRequest, 0, CompressedRequest.Length);
    RequestStream.Flush();

    Stream CompressedResponseStream = Request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
    byte[] CompressedResponseData = ReadToEnd(CompressedResponseStream);
    string DecompressedResponseData = SimpleZlib.Decompress(CompressedResponseData, null);

    ResponseRoot Return = Json.Deserialize<ResponseRoot>(DecompressedResponseData);
    string returnErrorCode = DecompressedResponseData.ToString();

    //AddLog(DecompressedResponseData);

    if (Return.err == 0 && returnErrorCode.Contains("id"))
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(DecompressedResponseData);
        //AddLog("Successful Purchase!");

        return 0;
    }
    else if (returnErrorCode.Contains("1503"))
    {
        //AddLog("Failed with 1503!");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (returnErrorCode.Contains("1512"))
    {
        // AddLog("Failed with 1512!");
        return 2;
    }

    return 3;
}
```

As stated above, ideally i would like to run both the "attachandbuy" and "buyorder" functions at the same time, and then eventually i will add a sell function, also running concurrently. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: If there aren't any dependencies between AttachAndBuy(), buy() and sell(), you can create 3 different bots for each function rather than doing it in one bot. It will give you a lot of flexibility around changes and deploying only that function on its own without disrupting any other.

Comment: WebRequest/WebResponse provide asynchrounous versions of these methods.: `GetRequestStreamAsync()`, `GetResponseAsync()` etc., plus the `[Stream].WriteAsync/ReadAsync` and all the other async methods of the Stream/derived classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by creating a list of tasks and executing them, this stops the main thread from being blocked while a call hasn't returned yet, e.g. -

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

for (int i = 0; i < numToBuy; i++)
{
    var task = new Task(() =>
    {
        AttachAndBuy()
    });

    tasks.Add(task);
    task.Start();
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

(Note: I've not actually tested this code, it's just a rough example)

Misunderstanding below -

<strike>You'll want to use some parallel programming for this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming?redirectedfrom=MSDN within your for loop e.g. -</strike>

```
private void RunBot()
{
    numToBuy = (int)nudNumToBuy.Value;

    for (int i = 0; i < numToBuy; i++)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Parallel.Invoke(() => AttachAndBuy(), () => BuyOrder());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wont this still lock up the program seeing as how im utilizing a while(true) loop? Also, i cant call buyOrder from RunBot as it requires a parameter passed from attachandbuy.

Comment: Yes it will, but I thought the goal was to run the two methods at the same time? From above - `As stated above, ideally i would like to run both the "attachandbuy" and "buyorder" functions at the same time`. Apologies if I misunderstood!

Comment: no i think you are right i did say that and that was me misspeaking. Can i call Parallel.Invoke in the attachandbuy function when i get the parameter i need to still have multithreading?

Comment: I think you're looking for a Task based solution if I'm reading right. Are you wanting the for loop to call `AttachAndBuy` and then continue to the next call of it while the previous one is executing?

Comment: yes, the goal would be to make this happen as fast as physically possible. right now with single threaded performance im not able to make the requests happen in a profitable fashion.